# If $a,b$ are linearly independent functions on an interval $I$, are they linearly independent on any interval $J$ contained in $I$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, wronskian

Let's say $~a,~ b~$ are linearly independent functions on an interval $~I~$. Are they linearly independent on any interval $~J~$ contained in $~I~$? If so, how do I prove it?

Let's say $~a,~ b~$ are instead linearly dependent functions on an interval $~I~$. Are they linearly dependent on any interval $~J~$ contained in $~I~$? If so, how do I prove it?

I have a feeling I'm supposed to use the Wronskian determinant for these but I'm not sure how to apply it.

Comment: What happens for  $a= x$, $b= x \mathbf{1}_{(-\infty,1]}+ x^2 \mathbf{1}_{(1,\infty)}$ ?

Comment: No, don't use the Wronskian determinant! Use your brain. Look for counterexamples. As a small hint, the answer to one of those questions is Yes, and the answer to the other one is No.

Answer (score 2):

**False**:

Take $~f(x) = x^2~$ and $~g(x) = x|x|~$. Then $~f, ~g~$ linearly independent over $~[−1, 1]~$ but dependent over $~[0, 1]~$.